# In Android ,how to receive GPS location continuously?

Tags: android, performance, gps, android-gps

Issue in onLocationChanged() function of location listener of android.location.LocationListener.

In Below code after requesting requestLocationUpdates of LocationManager, the onLocationChanged is called in uneven intervals, i.e i have set period at 1 second but i don't receive the location change after every second.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
public class SimplePositionProvider extends PositionProvider implements LocationListener {

public SimplePositionProvider(Context context, PositionListener listener) {
super(context, listener);

Log.i("SimplePositionProvider", "start");
if (!type.equals(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
type = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
}

}

public void startUpdates() {
Log.i("startUpdates", "start");
try {
Log.i("requestLocationUpdates", "start");
Log.i("TYPE", type);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(type, period, 0, this);
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
Log.e(TAG, "error");
}
}

public void stopUpdates() {
Log.i("stopUpdates", "start");
locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
Log.i("onLocationChanged", "start");
updateLocation(location);
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
Log.i("onStatusChanged", "start");
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
Log.i("onProviderEnabled", "start");
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
Log.i("onProviderDisabled", "start");
}

}
```

Comment: create a location service to get location continiusly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html), you should use [FusedLocationProviderClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient) to request location updates. If memory serves, that solution sends updates at the specified interval. You can get a `FusedLocationProviderClient` by calling `LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(Context context)`.

You can set the request expiration duration in [LocationRequest](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest) with `setExpirationDuration`, and then use something like this code when you start the updates to re-start after each expiry:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.myLooper());
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      if (expectingLocationUpdates) {
        restartLocationUpdates();
      }
    }
}, EXPIRATION_DURATION);
```

Answer (score 0):

[According to the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html), the `period` argument you are using is the minimum interval between location updates. If you want to get locations as fast as the location system updates, set `period` to zero.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue we are facing is ,location receiving is not stable ,it get disconnected after a time interval . In emulator no issue in receiving location continuously.

Comment: @BonnySebastian You should re-word your question. That's not what it seems to be asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use this class ..

```
    public class MyLocationService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyLocationService";
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000 * 30;;
    private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 0f;


    private final IBinder serviceBinder = new MyLocationService.RunServiceBinder();

    public MyLocationService() {
    }

    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),

    };

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");

        initializeLocationManager();

     /*   try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[1]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
        }*/



        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[0]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                try {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return;
                    }
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listener, ignore", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void removeUpdate(){
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                try {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return;
                    }
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listener, ignore", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void initializeLocationManager() {
        Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager - LOCATION_INTERVAL: " + LOCATION_INTERVAL + " LOCATION_DISTANCE: " + LOCATION_DISTANCE);
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        //   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        return null;
    }

    public class RunServiceBinder extends Binder {
        public MyLocationService getService() {
            return MyLocationService.this;
        }
    }


    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
        Location mLastLocation;

        public LocationListener(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
          //  Toast.makeText(MyLocationService.this, ""+provider, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
           // Toast.makeText(MyLocationService.this, ""+"checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mLastLocation.set(location);

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: It Take time to start and stops while placing on my glass table(same as my above code)